# Can I use php's fwrite with 644 file permissions?

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-permissions, fwrite

I am trying to set up automated .htaccess updating. This clearly needs to be as secure as possible, however right now the best I can do file permission-wise is 666.

What can I do to setup either my server or php code so that my script's `fwrite()` command will work with 644 or better? For instance is there a way to set my script(s) to run as owner?

**EDIT:**
I realized I actually just had a permissions issue, you should be able to use `fwrite` no problem with 644 permissions. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These suggestions were great, however I ultimately realized that the answer to my question is **YES - and you shouldn't have to do anything at all...** *as long as the Owner user of the file/directory you are trying to write to is the same user the script is running as.* My mistake was that I accidentally had my file ownership out of whack therefore needed higher permissions 666 and 777 in order to write to my files. Which makes sense because Wordpress can write to .htaccess with standard permissions.

Now I have things setup where a file running as `user1` is writing to a file owned by `user1:user1`, and no problems whatsoever. Directories set to 755, `.htaccess` file set to 644.

Answer (score 2):

The `apache` process should always run as `apache:apache` - if you must enable write permissions in executable (i.e. DocumentRoot) directories, create a group, add apache and set group write permissions (so `664`).

It's best to have `.htaccess` updated by a cron script reading config data from a database, as giving apache write permissions to executable directories is frowned upon in case a vulnerability in your code allows a malicious user to write new files to those directories.

Comment: +1 for cron. But if he's on a shared server, setting apache to the group will pretty much put his files at 99% of the original risk.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with using cron jobs... would I be able to have the cron script execute when an administrator hits an "Update .htaccess" button on my php page for instance? Or can they only be set to execute at timed intervals like every hour, day, month, etc.? I am on a dedicated host btw.

Comment: Yep, cron is a "time-based job scheduler". You can set the cron to run every minute (or two) and check for an entry in a db table with either an instruction code (safer) or the actual code to put in `.htaccess` (less safe). cron examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the process's owner. If you're on a shared server, see if they have suPHP as an option.